# How to rename dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, function, arguments

Suppose i have two data frames, `dm` and `suppdm`

```r
test <- function(inds) {
    a1 <- inds
    a2 <- paste("supp", a1, sep = '')
    
    print(class(a1))
    print(class(a2))
}

test(dm)
```

At this time, `a1` is the `dm` data frame, but `a2` is not `suppdm`, just character. How to enter a parameter and use two data frames? Does this belong to the renaming of the data frame?

---

*PS: it seems difficult to pass parameters in R function.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `assign` to create an object with a name given by a character string and use `get` to get the object given by that string.
Note that the name with the prefix `"supp"` will only exist in the function and is discarded on exit.

```r
test <- function(inds){
  a1 <- deparse(substitute(inds))
  a2 <- paste0("supp", a1)
  assign(a2, inds)
  out_df <- get(a2)
  
  print(class(a1))
  print(class(a2))
  print(class(out_df))
  
  out_df
}

head(test(iris))
#> [1] "character"
#> [1] "character"
#> [1] "data.frame"
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer,I understand assign and get a little,assign(a2, inds)，a2 is inds, but I want to get a2 is suppinds data frame,Do I have to add one more suppinds parameter?

Comment: @OrangePeel Now I don't understand, you have a data.frame named `suppinds` and you want `a2` to become that df based on the name `inds`? If that's the case, remove the `assign` instruction, `get(a2)` is what you want.

Comment: oh,yes,remove assign,only use get(a2),thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

A potentially interesting alternative is to use the [`mv`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gdata/versions/2.18.0/topics/mv) function available within the [`gdata`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gdata/index.html) package:

```r
library("gdata")
dfA <- data.frame(colA = c(1,2), colB = c(3,4))
ls()
# [1] "dfA"
# to: argument takes any string so conveniently it can be used 
#     with usual string manipulation functions
mv(from = "dfA", to = paste0("df", "B"))
ls()
# "dfB"
```

## Notes

- Concerning your observation:

  > *PS: it seems difficult to pass parameters in R function*

  That depends on the individual's perspective, R may be considered as easier or more challenging, depending on the developer's background, level of experience, etc. I reckon that's a subject for a longer conversation.
- `mv` offered within the `gdata`, makes use of `assign`, similarly to [the valid answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71584340/1655567) contributed by [@Rui Barradas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8245406/rui-barradas), plus provides some other gadgets for the argument checking and optional target environment. Whether it makes sense to rely on this package to accomplish this minor task is mostly a matter of taste/approach to handling dependencies.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Use your method, I got the result, but have a warning message: in rm(list = from, envir = envir) : object 'suppds' not found  ;   I didn't use the rm function

Comment: I very much agreed to say, I use SAS, the parameters in the SAS macro can be used anywhere, and the data set name, variable, value can also be replaced, and other characters can also be used to represent the data set, variable, value. When R, the data type has changed, the objects represented by the function parameters are different, and it is a bit difficult to understand.
Recently study R, I have to come to the oil, try to get started soon.

Comment: @OrangePeel mv removes the object, if not found in parent environment you may be getting the warning. You would have to post new / edit your question for someone to see why the warning is generated.

Comment: just @Rui Barradas said，remove assign ,only use get(a2),Thank you for your reply