# Properly using reprex package when generating examples that load libraries

Tags: r, reprex

I would like to use a [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) package when generating an answer/question<sup>1</sup> that utilises multiple packages. Say I want to provide the following answer

```r
library("gdata")
dfA <- data.frame(colA = c(1, 2), colB = c(3, 4))
ls()
mv(from = "dfA", to = paste0("df", "B"))
ls()
```

If I pass this code directly to *reprex* the output will be as follows:

```r
library("gdata")
#> gdata: read.xls support for 'XLS' (Excel 97-2004) files ENABLED.
#> 
#> gdata: Unable to load perl libaries needed by read.xls()
#> gdata: to support 'XLSX' (Excel 2007+) files.
#> 
#> gdata: Run the function 'installXLSXsupport()'
#> gdata: to automatically download and install the perl
#> gdata: libaries needed to support Excel XLS and XLSX formats.
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'gdata'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     nobs
#> The following object is masked from 'package:utils':
#> 
#>     object.size
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     startsWith
dfA <- data.frame(colA = c(1, 2), colB = c(3, 4))
ls()
#> [1] "dfA"
mv(from = "dfA", to = paste0("df", "B"))
ls()
#> [1] "dfB"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

There is a lost of irrelevant info related to the package load. An alternative is to suppress package startup messages:

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library("gdata"))
dfA <- data.frame(colA = c(1, 2), colB = c(3, 4))
ls()
#> [1] "dfA"
mv(from = "dfA", to = paste0("df", "B"))
ls()
#> [1] "dfB"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

The above reprex output is generated via:

```r
library("reprex")
reprex(x = {
    suppressPackageStartupMessages(library("gdata"))
    dfA <- data.frame(colA = c(1, 2), colB = c(3, 4))
    ls()
    mv(from = "dfA", to = paste0("df", "B"))
    ls()

}, venue = "so")
```

## Question

Is there a cleaner way to do this? Reprex offers `tidyverse_quiet` but I'm wondering if there is an intelligent way to "stretch" that argument to apply to multiple packages? In a hypothetical answer that loads multiple packages, I would like to avoid writing `suppressPackageStartupMessages` a number of times just to suppress unnecessary outputs.

Writing `package::function` may be onerous when calling multiple functions from various packages.

---

*<sup>1</sup>For reference, I started thinking on that that after contributing [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71586121/1655567) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71584004/1655567).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option to consider is to use knitr chunk options inside the reprex.  Obviously, these would apply to all code within the chunk although you could use multiple chunks for more control.

```
reprex(x = {
  #+ chunk1, message = FALSE
  library("gdata")
  dfA <- data.frame(colA = c(1, 2), colB = c(3, 4))
  ls()
  mv(from = "dfA", to = paste0("df", "B"))
  ls()
  }, venue = "so")
```

Which gives:

```r
library("gdata")
dfA <- data.frame(colA = c(1, 2), colB = c(3, 4))
ls()
#> [1] "dfA"
mv(from = "dfA", to = paste0("df", "B"))
ls()
#> [1] "dfB"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to run `suppressPackageStartupMessages` more than once.  You can do

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(gdata)
  library(tidyverse)
})
#> Warning: package 'tidyr' was built under R version 4.1.2
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 4.1.2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

You'll still see warnings, but most of the junk is suppressed.

For SO, you could shorten this to

```
suppressMessages({
  library(gdata)
  library(tidyverse)
})
```

I wouldn't do this routinely, because maybe some packages have useful messages.  It might also give newbies the wrong idea and have them using it in their own code, missing out on those messages.

If you want somewhat less suppression, you can use

```
library(gdata, quietly = TRUE)
library(tidyverse, quietly = TRUE)
```